# Enterprise Architect Model Search XML Format

Tags: c#, xml, add-in, enterprise-architect

I have written a few Add-Ins for Enterprise Architect in C#. I want to add a complex model search now in a similar manner. I have no issue running my add-in search. I believe my issue is with the XML Model Search Format. The only documentation that I can find is [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/xml_format_search_data.html).

I tried to use the example JScript and VB Script files in EA "JScript - Model Search (Attributes) Example". I cannot get that to give me output when I run it in EA. That has to be user error, I believe. I am using that code as an example to try to properly output my search results from a C# add-in.

I can't figure out what the value for `<ReportViewData UID=\"MySearchID\" >` should be? It seems like it should be the UID of the search. How does one find that? It is missing from the JScript example, as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have a properly formatted XML Search Format file I can test? Just modifying a known working file by hand to match an element in my repo and importing the results would be a huge help. I can't find any documentation other than what I have linked above.

Comment: I posted this question here because I have never found much relevant information on the [Sparx System Forum](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi). One thing I learned today is that the default search for that forum is the past week. One has to click the search button and select a search period beyond the last week. For the last 3 years, I thought there was nothing relevant on the Sparx Forum. I did find a couple of people who have had my same question asked above. It does not appear to have ever been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My big issue was not using the `out` keyword in my C# function for the `XMLResults` value. The function declaration in Thomas's answer was that fix.

The value for "MySearchID" is the GUID for the search. After creating the add-in search using the builder in EA export the search as XML. The XML export file contains the GUID for the search. Use that value to replace "MySearchID". Here is my XML output generated by a C# add-in as an example of a file that has worked:

```
<ReportViewData UID="{74945F94-D210-4f45-8639-784DAE0DAB1F}">
  <Fields>
    <Field name="CLASSGUID" />
    <Field name="CLASSTYPE" />
    <Field name="Object" />
    <Field name="Type" />
    <Field name="Stereotype" />
  </Fields>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Field name="CLASSGUID" value="{A16DD03A-B1B2-4269-A058-0AB14B933388}" />
      <Field name="CLASSTYPE" value="Class" />
      <Field name="Object" value="Class1" />
      <Field name="Type" value="Class" />
      <Field name="Stereotype" value="AffineConversion" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Field name="CLASSGUID" value="{44E11CA0-1FAE-47ee-9088-D3106F320C57}" />
      <Field name="CLASSTYPE" value="Class" />
      <Field name="Object" value="Class2" />
      <Field name="Type" value="Class" />
      <Field name="Stereotype" value="MessagePort" />
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</ReportViewData>
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting your own answer after letting me do the work.

Answer (score 4):

`Repository.RunModelSearch` does not return any results. It just runs the model search (Ctrl-F) as if the user had selected it and passed a search term. You can add your own XML which the model search window will display (so it's formatted correctly). There are other ways to retrieve data from the model. Use either `Repository.SQLSearch` or `Repository.GetElementSet`.

Assume you have the following SQL search named "test":

```
SELECT  ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, Object_Type AS CLASSTYPE, Name FROM t_object
WHERE Name LIKE '*<Search Term>*'
```

And your XML looks like this:

```
<ReportViewData UID="MySearchID" >
 <Fields>
         <Field name="CLASSGUID"/>
         <Field name="CLASSTYPE"/>
 </Fields>

 <Rows>
         <Row>
                 <Field name="CLASSGUID" value="{99660FA1-6927-41bf-9676-521A6C852884}"/>
                 <Field name="CLASSTYPE" value="Class"/>
         </Row>
 </Rows>
</ReportViewData>
```

If you run `Repository.RunModelSearch ("test", "Class1", "", xml)` it will append the class with the supplied guid irrespective to what else has been found. It will even display the class as object if you change the CLASSTYPE to Object.

As fas as I understood `ReportViewData UID="MySearchID"` is used to preserve search settings (column widths etc.) and is of less importance.

Honestly I can hardly imagine a use case for this method ;-)

P.S.: I asked Sparx about this and here is the reply:

```
public object MyAddinSearch(EA.Repository Repository, String SearchText, out String XMLResults)
```

> The XMLResults parameter needs to be passed by reference.  The XML results generated by this function need to be assigned to this parameter for further processing by EA.  The return value for this method simply requires a non-empty result to indicate that results should be displayed in EA.  For example, simply returning a boolean true value is sufficient.

Comment: I think an example of a XML search result would help me greatly. Using the buttons found in the toolbar in the Find in Project->Bulider window I can use the "Export Search" to create an XML definition file of a search. I can use the "Import Search" to import a file formatted the same way to import a search definition. That file is different from the XML Model Search Format, which has results in it, not the definition of a search. I was hoping I could import a working file to test it, but I misunderstood the function of the Import Search button.

Comment: Now, that being said, If I had a XML Search Format File that was properly formatted, I can create an add-in the simply returns a canned properly formatted result. I just need to rule out formatting issues as my problem. A properly formatted example would be very helpful!

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the help. My use case: I have a bunch of Add-In code that does things like sync a MS project schedule and produce reports in MS Excel from EA. Using the object model lets me do interesting things like determine if an element is in a boundary on a particular diagram. Maybe I could do that in SQL, but I didn't because I wanted to make it easy to use the MS Office Add-Ins too. So, I have a bunch of infrastructure in C# Add-In code. I'm generating a document inside of EA, and I want to use the capabilities from my existing add-in code to conduct searches.

Comment: Your XML example helped me to find a formatting problem in my output. Thanks. I'm following the the [Add-In Search  documentation from Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/add_in_search.html). I think my problem now is I don't understand the Return Value required. The documentation shows the return value as a variant in VB. The description only states that "The method must return a value for the results to be displayed." Does this mean any value? I think I must be missing something

Comment: Also, I think I may have found a way to find the value for "MySearchID". After I create the add-in search using the builder in EA and giving it the Add-in name and function name, I exported that search as XML. That file gives me a GUID for the search that I created. I think that value is what I should use to replace "MySearchID". It is hard to tell since I can't get it to work.

Comment: I don't know which return value you're talking of (see the first sentence of my answer).

Comment: I'm talking about this (from EA documentation linked in my comment): 

The method that runs the search must be structured in the following way:
 
`variant <method name> (Rep as Repository, SearchText as String, XMLResults as String)`

Maybe we are talking about different things or I just don't understand something.

Comment: Your link just references the XML format. It is used in `RunModelSearch`. `RunModelSearch` does not return anything. Read my post.

Comment: I was referring to this link:  [Add-In Search documentation from Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/add_in_search.html) not XML format link. I'm not trying to use the `Repository.RunModelSearch` method. I have a method in an add-in that is called as described on the documentation page linked in this comment. My method runs, it receives the `SearchText` value and writes a properly formatted XML file to `XMLResults`. I do not see the results in the search window. I am unsure of what the value or type `variant` retrurn value should be in a C# call.

Comment: My bad :-( Check Geerts navigator (it's open source IIRC): http://bellekens.com/ea-navigator/ There's an add-in search inside and it's C#. I'd know the answer for Perl where you can create a variant. It's probably trivial but Geert's navigator (and his blog) are valuable anyway.

Comment: @MrSnrub I think there return value can be anything. I've never used it as such, but I think if you return "value" it should be fine.

Comment: See my edits. I'll try that myself but have to find some Cxx compiler(/IDE)